# Child class method not overriding the method of the same signature in parent

Tags: java, inheritance

Why is my child class method not overriding the method of the same signature in its parent class?

### Summary:

I have a class `PlayerPaddle` that extends an abstract class `Paddle`, which extends the abstract class Actor (the context here is a pong game). `Paddle` and `PlayerPaddle` both have a method with the same signature:

```
public void moveDown()
```

The intention is to have the `PlayerPaddle` `moveDown` method override that of `Paddle`. The problem here is when I call `this.moveDown()` inside `PlayerPaddle`, only the `moveDown` method of `Paddle` is called.

### The details:

Breakpoints set on `moveDown()` in `Paddle` are tripped, while breakpoints on `moveDown()` in `PlayerPaddle` never trip. I also tried `@Override` on the `PlayerPaddle` `moveDown` method, but it still calls the `Paddle` `moveDown` method.

### The context:

The goal is for `PlayerPaddle` objects to move up/down at a different speed than other `Paddle` objects. So the same problem occurs for the `moveUp` method as well.

### Code below:

```
abstract public class Actor {
    public void releasedEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}

abstract public class Paddle extends Actor {
     public void moveDown() { // this method is called
          body.setVel(0, Game.dX / 10.);   
     }
}


public class PlayerPaddle extends Paddle {
    @Override
    public void moveDown() { // this method never gets called
       body.setVel(0,  Game.dX );
    } 

    public void receiveEvent(KeyEvent e) {
       if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
          this.moveUp(); 
       } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
          this.moveDown(); // Want to call moveDown() inside PlayerPaddle
       }
    }

}
```

I am happy to provide clarification.

Comment: It looks like it should work. How did you determine which method was being called?

Comment: Try logging a message (even a `System.out.println()` will do).  That might be more reliable than trying to keep track of where you are with a debugger.  Works better for me anyway....

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: show your code where you call the method actually

Comment: If this didn't work, Java wouldn't be polymorphic. Which it is...

Comment: How you are calling moveDown()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the simple case, it works:

```
public class Test{

  public static void main(String args[])
  {     
    new PlayerPaddle().receiveEvent();
  }
}
abstract class Actor {
  public void releasedEvent(KeyEvent e) {
  }
}
abstract class Paddle extends Actor {
  public void moveDown() { // this method is called
      System.out.println("paddle");
  }
}
class PlayerPaddle extends Paddle {
  @Override
  public void moveDown() { // this method never gets called
   System.out.println("playerpaddle");
  } 
  public void receiveEvent() {
     this.moveDown(); // Want to call moveDown() inside PlayerPaddle      
  }
}
```

It calls the PlayerPaddle one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was right. I had a mix up with my class names.